# File pickup from ftp directory

Tags: mule, cloudhub

I have deployed an application in CloudHub with the FTP connector at the event source. It picks up the file whenever a file is dropped in the FTP directory. If I deploy application 0.1v and 2 workers, and a file arrives from the FTP directory, how should the application react?

- Anyone could explain the above scenario?

Comment: The question lacks focus. Are you asking about a specific problem? What have you tried? What are you really asking? Why the number of vcores should make any difference? Questions should be specific.

Comment: Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question.